# Вывод текста на экран, поверх всех окон

Tags: c#, winapi, wpf, .net-4.0

Пытаюсь написать программку, коротая выводит на экран текущее время поверх всех окон. Пробовал выводить прозрачную форму с текстовой меткой и свойством **Topmost = true**. Но такая форма перекрывается, если запустить полноэкранное приложение (игру например).

Как вывести текст на экран, поверх всех окон, и что бы полноэкранные приложения не перекрывали его ***(или хотя бы по верх одного конкретного полноэкранного приложения (игры))***?

Comment: Это в принципе невозможно. Обязательное чтение по теме: [_How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?_](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx).

Comment: @VladD, разве есть что-то невозможное? =)

Comment: Если это не возможно, то как с этим Fraps справляется (показывает кол-во FPS прямо в игре в полноэкранном(!) режиме)?

Comment: @Zer0CooL: А вы статью читали? Допустим, что вы сделаете тот же трюк — чей текст будет выше, ваш или Fraps'а?

Comment: @0xFFh: Есть, конечно. Есть куча логически невозможных вещей. В статье, на которую я ссылаюсь, о таких как раз и говорится.

Answer (score 1):

Например, сделать прозрачную форму с параметром **TOPMOST** и **MAXIMIZED**( хотя вовсе не обязательно максимизировать форму ), внутри которой создать текстовое поле, в котором, в свою очередь, отображать текст.

Для надежности можно в "скоростном" таймере беспрерывно устанавливать форму видимой и делать её поверх всех остальных окон системы.

Comment: Я же писал что пробовал так делать. Не получается. Полноэкранные приложения перекрывают форму с параметром TOPMOST.

Answer (score 0):

Вам верно ответили, TOPMOST и по таймеру.
А игры работающие на OpenGL/DirectX выводят мимо ОС, сразу на монитор. Их можно перекрыть только вмешиваясь в OpenGL/DirectX. Поищите как работают WallHack.